# Is Google Maps Android API v2 free?

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

There is no courtesy limit for Google Maps Android API v2 on my console, is it a free service?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the FAQ states that:

What usage limits apply to the Maps API?

"Web sites and applications using the Google Maps API may at no cost generate up to 25,000 map loads per day for each service.

If your application exceeds these usage limits you must respond in one of the following ways in order to continue using the Maps API in your application:

Modify your Maps API application such that the number of map loads generated per day is below the usage limit for each service that your application uses;
   Enroll for automated billing of excess map loads in the Google APIs Console; or
   Purchase a Maps API for Business license

In order to accommodate sites that experience short term spikes in usage, the usage limits will only take effect for a given site once that site has exceeded the limits for more than 90 consecutive days.

Non-profits and applications deemed in the public interest (as determined by Google at its discretion) are not subject to these usage limits. For example, a disaster relief map is not subject to the usage limits even if it has been developed and/or is hosted by a commercial entity. In addition we recommend that eligible Non-profits apply for a Maps API for Business license through the Google Earth Outreach Grants program, which provides a number of benefits.

A precise definition of what constitutes a 'map load' is provided here. Details on pricing can be found here."

https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#usagelimits

Comment: I Think that is the limit of map v3 service (v2 is deprecated)... seems have no limit

Comment: Google Maps API is different from Google Maps Android API

Comment: At https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#usage_apis "The Google Earth API, and native Maps APIs for mobile platforms such as Android and iOS are not affected. Use of the embed feature of Google Maps, and other Google products that offer an embed feature that includes a map, are not affected by these limits."